# Не могу получить все заголовки в ответе запроса от FastAPI, с помощью Axios (React)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs, axios, fastapi

У меня имеется серверная часть веб-приложения написанная на FastAPI(python), которая принимает на вход изображение, производит некоторые операции с ним и затем возвращает обработанное изображение.
Вот часть кода, который формирует возвращаемые заголовки и отправляет обработанное изображение:

```
headers = {}
headers['crop_warn'] = json.dumps(current_user.crop_warn)
headers['cardio'] = json.dumps(current_user.cardio)
headers['software_version'] = json.dumps(current_user.software_version)
headers['research_warn']= json.dumps(current_user.research_warn)
headers['client-prob'] = current_user.client_prob
headers['color-mode'] = current_user.color_mode
headers['language'] = current_user.language
#Код
#Код
#Код
return Response(content=response.content, headers=headers, media_type='image/png')
```

Клиентская часть написана на React. Вот её код, отвечающий за отправку и приём изображения.

```
let url = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('file').files[0])
setOriginalUrl(url)
setLoading(true)
setProcessing(true)
const conig = {
  headers:{
    Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
    SOP':'file: '+transliterate(file).toString+' (On-line proccessing)'
  } 
  const fd = new FormData()
  fd.append('file',document.getElementById('file').files[0])
  axios.post('http://192.168.0.156:8080/predict/',fd,conig).then((response)=>{
     const responseHeaders = response.headers;
     console.log(responseHeaders)}).catch((error)=>{
        console.log('Произошла ошибка: ',error)
     })
```

Моя проблема заключается в том, что из всех headers, которые я отправляю из FastAPI, я вижу только два:

```
{content-length: '634211', content-type: 'image/png'}
```

Буду благодарен, если кто подскажет в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (например, стоит дать более внятный заголовок)

Comment: вы отправляете заголовки запроса, потом получаете залоговки ответа сервера. какая связь между ними?